# CSS Positioning relative to corner of Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several divs within a larger divs. Is it possible to position all these divs relative to the top left corner of the parent div? This will make positioning easier for certain tasks as all the inner divs' coordinates will be relative to the same reference point. At the moment using `position: relative` just offsets its position from where it would be at without being affected by `position: relative`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the parent/containing div to `position:relative`.  Then, set the child divs to `postion:absolute`.   The children will then be positioned absolutely, but relative to the containing div, not relative to the overall page.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/GgNsH/.

HTML:

```
<div id"otherStuff" style="height: 100px; background-color: #777;"></div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="child1" class="child"></div>
    <div id="child2" class="child"></div>
    <div id="child3" class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {position: relative;}
.child {position: absolute; height: 10px; width: 10px; background-color: #777;}
#child1 {top: 10px; left: 10px}
#child2 {top: 30px; left: 30px}
#child3 {top: 50px; left: 50px}
```

Each child will be positioned at it's top/left value from the top/left corner of the container.

It works because that's how `position: absolute` works.  It positions the element relative to the first positioned parent (a parent that has a position value of `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`) or if no parents are positioned, then it uses the top/left corner of the document as the reference.  This is not a trick, but how it's documented to work and it's extremely useful.

Comment: I added an example to my answer and a little bit of an explanation.  You can see tab #4 on this page for more explanation: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: Note that the parent can be `position: absolute` as well as `position: relative`, both create a new positioning context for child elements.