# Aligning text to corner of page header

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to align the header text (blue background) to the right/bottom corner of the header so that it is ALWAYS in that position no matter the device (responsive).  So far it looks different on every device I've tested on, so I'm stumped.  I've spent ALL DAY on this and gotten nowhere. Can anyone help?

Thank you!

[URL removed for privacy]

P.S. I have read [CSS Positioning relative to corner of Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576960/css-positioning-relative-to-corner-of-div) and tried to implement it, but am still stuck!

Comment: Could you put the part of code related to the question that you are using right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give `position: relative` to the parent and `position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0;` to the child element and the child will be positioned relatively to the parent (it will be at the bottom right corner). Here is an example:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: violet;
}

.target {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="target">TARGET</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Figured it out.  One of the parent divs had relative positioning and once removed, this solution worked.